# which is best?? muliple table or single table?

Tags: php, mysql

HI I am still confused that whether I need to use multiple table in a single database or single table in single database??

I do have near about 30 columns for one record.

Comment: What are you modelling? You want one table per "thing" - Customers, Orders, Products..

Comment: It's hard to give a detailed recommendation based on the as far given information, but you'd undoubtely like to read on the subject ["database normalization"](http://www.google.com/search?q=database+normalization).

Comment: The goal is to not repeat data in your database. You might really need 30 columns unique to a piece of data. More than likely, you'll want to break it into other tables and use foreign keys to link it all together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's going to be highly dependent on what kind of data you're storing, but it's quite common for databases to have multiple tables.  [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is the term you want to search for and read up on.

When I say "what kind of data you're storing" I don't just mean in general terms like text vs. numeric data.  It depends more on what specifically the table in your application represents.  If you're storing Customer data and Product data in the same table, it almost certainly should be split into two tables (or possibly more).  If all of your data can be described as one type, then it might be okay to have only one table.

Comment: It also relates to the number of records you might have for a given piece of information. For instance if you havea user and you are going to store his username (well he only has one username) and his email (Oh he can have three emails) then this should be in two tables.